# How do I iteratively select rows in pandas based on column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm a complete newbie at pandas so a simpler (though maybe not the most efficient or elegant) solution is appreciated.  I don't mind a bit of brute force if I can understand the answer better.

If I have the following Dataframe:

```
A    B    C 
0    0    1
0    1    1
```

I want to loop through columns "A", "B" and "C" in that order and during each iteration select all the rows for which the current column is "1" and none of the previous columns are and save the result and also use it in the next iteration.

So when looking at column A, I wouldn't select anything.  Then when looking at column B I would select the second row because B==1 and A==0.  Then when looking at column C I would select the first row because A==0 and B==0.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: On the first iteration (column A) there's no output as nothing matches the criteria, on the second iteration (column B), the expected output is the second row:

0 0 1


and when looking at column C (the third iteration) the expected output is the first row:


0 0 1

Answer (score 1):

Create a boolean mask:

```
m = (df == 1) & (df.cumsum(axis=1) == 1)
d = {col: df[m[col]].index.tolist() for col in df.columns if m[col].sum()}
```

Output:

```
>>> m
       A      B      C
0  False  False   True
1  False   True  False
2  False  False   True

>>> d
{'B': [1], 'C': [0, 2]}
```

I slightly modified your dataframe:

```
>>> df
   A  B  C
0  0  0  1
1  0  1  1
2  0  0  1
```

**Update**

For the expected output on my sample:

```
for rows, col in zip(m, df.columns):
    if m[col].sum():
        print(f"\n=== {col} ===")
        print(df[m[col]])
```

Output:

```
=== B ===
   A  B  C
1  0  1  1

=== C ===
   A  B  C
0  0  0  1
2  0  0  1
```

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Good catch :) +1

Comment: Does OP only want the `index`? in that case isnt `df.idxmax(1)` sufficient? ie `df.idxmax(1).reset_index().groupby(0).agg(list)`. I am not quite sure of just the index or rather OP is trying to rearrange the df such that he has an upper triangle maxtrix

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: @onyambu. I returned the index because the expected output is not clear. With index, it's easy to extract rows. I updated my answer with a simple print.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need a direct use of [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html)

> Return index of first occurrence of maximum over requested axis.
>
> NA/null values are excluded.

---

```
>>> df.idxmax()
A    0
B    1
C    0
dtype: int64
```

The values above are the indexes for which your constraints are met. `1` for `B` means that the second row was "selected". `0` for C, same. The only issue is that, if nothing is found, it'll also return `0`.

To address that, you can use `where`

```
>>> df.idxmax().where(~df.eq(0).all())
```

This will make sure that `NaN`s are returned for all-zero columns.

```
A    NaN
B    1.0
C    0.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Yes. I didn't see it. Sorry

Comment: There is a subtlety: **select all the rows**. `idxmax` returns only one row (index)

Comment: @Corralien not sure if I follow. I believe OP wants the `idxmax` indeed. What they meant was to find that for all columns.

Comment: For example, if there are 2 rows with 1 in C and all previous columns are set to 0 then you have to select the 2 rows not the first. Check my answer, you will understand ;)